# Is it possible to inherit custom class from String?

Tags: swift, oop

I want to use my custom class as a String. Is it possible in Swift? For example, I want to do something like this:

```
label.text = CustomClass()
```

Comment: No. `String` is a struct, which do not support inheritance. What are you trying to achieve by subclassing?

Comment: You can, however, use [Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) of `String` in order to add custom behaviour.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to inherit from `String` in Swift. It is a `struct`, and they do not support inheritance.

One possibility for the use case you showed is to extend `UILabel`* to wrap and unwrap your type, given that it can transform *itself* to and from a string. In other words, if your class has these abilities:

```
class CustomClass {
    var stringValue: String {
        // Create a string somehow
    }

    init(stringValue: String) {
        // Configure
    }
}
```

Then a helper property on `UILabel` (or whatever) can hide those operations for clients:

```
extension UILabel {
    var myText: CustomClass? {
        get { return self.text.flatMap(CustomClass.init(stringValue:) }
        set { self.text = newValue?.stringValue }
    }
}
```

so that you can write `label.myText = instanceOfCustomClass`.

If necessary -- i.e., you find yourself needing to do this for several types -- you can even extract the "transform to/from string" to a protocol, rather than relying on a specific concrete type.

---

*I'm assuming iOS here; the same principle applies for *any* thing that has a `var text: String? { get set }`, though.